# Qt Programming and computations which take long time

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am new on Qt programming. I have to make some computations which take long time. I use an edit box and two button named as "start" and "stop". The edit box is used for the initialization. Start button starts the computation. While the computation is going on, I must be able to stop the computation whenever I want. But when I start the computation by clicking the start button. As expected, I cannot click any component on the window until the computation is completed.

I want to use the components (especially stop button) on the window normally while the computation is performing. But I am not good on the threads, I am looking for an easier method. Is there any simple solution?

Comment: Each answer below has been downvoted.  Would the person doing so be kind enough to explain why?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is very strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use threads (perhaps synchronizing them by sending messages on pipes to self), or use [timer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#startTimer) (with a 0 millisecond delays, this is how idle processing is done in Qt).

Answer (score 16):

There are a couple of options.

### 1. Subclass QRunnable

Subclass [QRunnable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qrunnable.html#details) and use [QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthreadpool.html#details) to run it in a separate thread. To communicate with the UI, use signals. Example of this:

```
class LongTask: public QRunnable
{
    void run()
    {
       // long running task
    }
};

QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new LongTask);
```

Note that you don't need to worry about managing the thread or the lifetime of your QRunnable. For communicating, you can connect your custom signals before starting the QRunnable.

### 2. Use [QtConcurrent::run](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtconcurrentrun.html#details)

This is a different approach and might not suit your problem. Basically, the way it works is the following: you get a handle to the future return value of the long task. When you try to retrieve the [return value](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfuture.html#result), it will either give it to you immediately or wait for the task to finish if it hasn't already. Example:

```
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(longProcessing, param1, param2);

// later, perhaps in a different function:
int result = future.result();
```

### 3. Subclass QThread

You probably don't need this, but it isn't hard either. This one is very similar to #1 but you need to manage the thread yourself. Example:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    void run() 
    {
        // long running task
    }
};

QThread* thread = new MyThread(this); // this might be your UI or something in the QObject tree for easier resource management
thread.start();
```

Similarly to QRunnable, you can use signals to talk to the UI.

Comment: Subclassing `QThread` is not the preferred way to create threads in Qt : http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 4):

In your computation you can put `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` so that GUI events also get processed. This will omit usage of threads.

Comment: That will only work if the blocking function consists of a loop of which one iteration runs reasonably fast. If one iteration takes long, the UI will freeze. Similarly, if there is no loop at all, it will only get one processEvents call and then freeze.

Comment: @TamásSzelei Agree. OP didn't clarify word *computation* and asked for an **easiest** method. So here it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your computation occur in a different thread than your GUI.  When the GUI recieves a signal that the stop button is pressed, you change a flag value which your computation thread periodically checks.  When the flag is set, you can terminate the computation thread.