# Questions about implementing QThread in my application?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qthread

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702086/gui-design-issues-using-c-qt-on-windows-vista), I am now trying to incorporate multithreading.

According to [the links given by karlphillip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9702182/193619), I understand that the documentation about subclassing QThread is not to be followed and to use `moveToThread()` as explained. Now I see that default implementation of QThread `run()` has only an `exec()` which must then be ended by calling `quit()` when worker thread has finished operations. I have a few questions now so that I understand things better:

```
QApplication* ptrApp=new QApplication(argc,argv);
QThread* th=new QThread;
MyClass* obj=new MyClass;
obj->moveToThread(th);
QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(started()),obj,SLOT(someFunct()));
QObject::connect(obj,SIGNAL(over()),th,SLOT(quit()));
th->start();
//some GUI code in main thread here
return ptrApp->exec();
```

1. What happens if I continue to use `someFunct()` even after I emit `over()` from within `someFunct()`? Is it undefined behaviour or normal?
2. Which thread would `obj` now be associated with (while the rest of the code after emitting `over()` is still executing in `someFunct`)? My understanding is: it cannot be in `th` when I have `quit()` that thread... `quit()` will be queued until the `exec()` in the main thread executes it which will cause the `exec()` in `run()` of `th` to exit (I hope I am not making a mistake here). I assume that thread is no longer existent.
3. Once slot `quit()` for `th` is executed, is it safe to assume that the thread has indeed quit or should I further connect `finished()` signal of `th` to some slot to be absolutely sure?

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't matter if the event loop is terminated, `somefunct()` will continue to run until it gives control back to the now extinct loop.
2. `obj` stays associated to the thread, so if a signal connected to one of its slots is emitted, the slot won't run but it will be queued for when/if the thread is restarted.

   If the `QThread` object is deleted, `obj->thread()` returns 0, so I suppose this would be equivalent to calling `obj->moveToThread(0)` and according to the documentation:

   > If targetThread is zero, all event processing for this object and its children stops.
3. `quit()` terminates the event loop, then the `finished()` signal is emitted from the thread, and the thread terminates. 

   So, even when you receive the `finished()` signal, you shouldn't assume that the thread is finished yet. You can use `QThread::wait` from the main thread, after you receive that signal to ensure that.

   If the thread is in the finishing state, the `QThread` destructor already calls `wait`, so you can safely delete the thread after the `finished()` signal (with `deleteLater()` to be even safer).

Comment: thanks

1. ya that's the behaviour i was noticing...just wanted to make sure it's not undefined/illegal or something

2. ok...pls tell me what happens if i delete the QThread pointer `th` (now as we cannot restart the thread anymore i suppose)

3. for `quit()` i understand that it will be in queue until `exec()` in the main thread executes it...but `finished()` is a signal which shouldn't require any event loop and it being the ultimate stuff to be done by the terminating thread, why is `QThread::wait()` required additionally as you point out once i make use of the `finished()` signal?

Comment: For 2. you can stop and restart the thread as often as you want. And for 3. emitting a signal doesn't require an event loop. The slot to which you connect it should be in another thread with a running event loop anyway (the thread eventloop can't receive its own finished() signal). But after looking in the QThread's source, I think you can just wait for the finished signal in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

*1. What happens if I continue to use `someFunct()` even after I emit `over()` from within `someFunct()`? Is it undefined behaviour or normal?*

As you are using direct connections, emitting `over` will call directly the function `quit`, **which stops the event loop and return from the exec in the thread run method.** Which means `someFunct()` will not finish its execution and the objects inside it are either lost or in a partial modified state.

*2. Which thread would obj now be associated with (while the rest of the code after emitting over() is still executing in someFunct)?*

As said previously `somefunct` will not finish its execution. But I believe any objects associated with this thread will remain as such. I say I believe because there is no solid assertion anywhere, but it make sense the most. [As mentioned in the doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#exit), for these objects to send or receive events the thread must be started again....

*3. Once slot quit() for th is executed, is it safe to assume that the thread has indeed quit or should I further connect finished() signal of th to some slot to be absolutely sure?*

`quit()` terminates the event loop and return where `exec()` was called.

Notice that the object Qthread is not the thread. so until you enter `exec()`, it is the main thread which is running... As well as it is the main thread which runs after the `exec`.

Anyway these are some great questions...